# How to keep frozen puff pastry dough keep its shape

Tags: puff-pastry

Whenever I cut semi thawed frozen puff pastry dough with a round cookie cutter, the shapes turns oval when I bake them.  How can I prevent this?

Comment: Do I understand it right, that you mean "puff pastry turning oval" by the puff pastry that doesn't puff at the edges? If so: Please look at [this question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/35107/23376) & [answer](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/35110/23376).

Answer (score 1):

It's the semi part of semi-thawed that's the problem, it needs to be thawed through and an even temperature throughout. If you have uneven temperature in the pastry when it goes into the oven you will have uneven baking. Keep it in the fridge until it's all thawed, then roll it.

Comment: Will that not let the butter melt and result in chewy pastry? Usually it's best to keep puff pastry as cold as possible.

Comment: I didn't put it very well, did I? What I was getting at was you need it thawed and a consistent temperature throughout. I've edited accordingly.